# elastic how to group by and sum

Tags: database, elasticsearch, group-by

I have an elastic query.
I have a value corresponding to each website. I would like to group by website and sum all the value. Is it possible ? how can I do it ? Thanks

````
  "size": 4000,
  "query": {
    "exists": {
        "field": "site.website"
            }
        }
    } ```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query will group by website, and sum the value of the fields you want.

```
GET /<your-index>/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "websites": {
      "terms": { "field": "site.website"},
      "aggs": {
        "total": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "<your field here>"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

see here for more information: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html